# Add Attributes to a custom component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am new to react and trying to make an authentication page. I try to modify the template from MUI and the link is as below:
https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/master/docs/src/pages/premium-themes/onepirate

In the SignUp.js, I try to add more attributes like maxLength and default value. But they don't work. I am wondering what causes the issue.

I tried to handle the situation with JavaScript, but I am thinking if there is a simpler solution.

```js
                <Field
                  fullWidth
                  component={RFTextField}
                  disabled={submitting || sent}
                  required
                  name="password"
                  autoComplete="new-password"
                  label="Password"
                  type="password"
                  margin="normal"
                  value="abc" //Not working
                  maxLength="8" //Not working
                />
```

Comment: Have you take a look on "Custom Input" section in this [link](https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/api/Field)?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work too. Not sure what goes wrong.

Comment: {(props) => (
                    <div>
                      <RFTextField
                        value="test"
                      />
                    </div>
                  )}

Comment: I think you should use this `import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField'`. Instead from `RFTextField`.